# Cocoa OSX: How can I make an image draggable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a panel with an image on it, and I want to make it so that you can copy a file (not the image,the image is only going to server as an icon for the file) into a folder by “dragging” the image outside of the application and into any other application that accepts files being dragged into it (ex. Finder). How can I do this?

I implemented the [NSDraggingSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, but I’m not sure how to make the image draggable. It is currently inside of an `ImageView`, which is inside of an `ImageViewCell`.

Here is the protocol I implemented:

```
#import "DragNDropView.h"

@implementation 
-(NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext: (NSDraggingContext) context{
  switch(context){
    case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
      return NSDragOperationCopy;
      break;
    default:
      return NSDragOperationNone;
      break;
  }
}

-(void) draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint) screenPoint{
   NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
   NSPaseBoardItem *contents = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc]
                                inithWithPasteboardPreopertyList:SDKFileName ofType:NSFileContentsPboardType];
   [pboard writeObjects[NSArray arrayWithObjects:contents, nil]];
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
  SDKFileName = @"example.example";
  [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the method `- (id)initWithCoder(NSCode *)coder` and I also added 
`- (BOOL)acceptesFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)event { return YES; }`