# Draggable Image View

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an image that is about 14000px by 14000px. I want to put it in a view and then be able to drag that image around to change what is seen. Is there a native way to do this or a custom class that has already been written or will I have to do it myself?

Comment: Does NSScrollView have a setting to do this by default? From what I have seen I don't see that so I would have to override the class myself.

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS**

1) [drag and drop image around the screen](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/) : Using UITouch To Drag An Image Around The Screen

2) [Drag And Drop objects](https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin) : Drag and drop objects contended in a scrollable image gallery

3) [Basic drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios)

For **Mac**

I don't think there is any ready-made way is available for you with mac os.You need to implement the [NSDraggingSource's – draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) as required by you. Unfortunately  the method "-draggedImage:endedAt:operation:" got deprecated in OS X v10.7 and later. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326329/cocoa-osx-how-can-i-make-an-image-draggable) for implementing the NSDraggingSource protocol.

draggingSession:movedToPoint:
Invoked when the drag moves on the screen.

**- (void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session movedToPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint**

--**session**: The dragging session.

--**screenPoint**: The point where the drag moved to, in screen coordinates.

I hope this will be useful for you...Happy coding :-)

Comment: I will take a look at these, but I was creating a Mac OSX app not an iOS app.